# updating all values on a row in a haskell matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix

I have such a code;

```
type El  = Int
type Idx = Int
type Mat a = [[a]]
type Row a = [a]
mapr :: Idx -> (Row El -> Row El) -> Mat El -> Mat El
mapr ----- ??????

main = do
        let a = [[2,1,-1,8],[-3,-1,2,-11],[-2,1,2,-3]]
        let res = mapr 2 a
```

By using `mapr` function type, I want to update all values on a row on `a` matrix. Let's say I want to increase all the values in a specific row by 1. But the way I have explained mapr function is wrong. How should I modify my code to update values on a row on matrix `a` by using `mapr` function type?

Comment: `!!` is little use here (and incidentally, seldom makes sense in Haskell generally – even where it does the job, it's terribly inefficient). Try it with [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) and pattern matching.

Comment: Your call to `mapr` is missing the update function to use to update row 2 in the matrix `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains several problems:

- the `mapr` function should take three arguments (an index, a function that should be applied to the row, and a matrix), but the stub implementation contains only two

  `mapr idx f m = ...`
- the `+1` in the definition of mapr should be replaced by the function that is provided as an argument to `mapr`

  `mapr idx f m = ... f ...`
- there should be parentheses around `+1`

  `(+1)`
- your `mapr` expects a function of type `[a] -> [a]`; `+1` doesn't fit the bill, you need `map (+1)`

Altogether, we get:

```
type El  = Int
type Idx = Int
type Mat a = [[a]]
type Row a = [a]

mapr :: Idx -> (Row El -> Row El) -> Mat El -> Mat El  
mapr idx f m = [ m!!i | i <- [0.. (idx-1)]] ++ [(f (m !! idx))] ++ [m!!i | i <- [(idx+1) .. (length m-1)]]

main = 
  let
    a = [[2,1,-1,8],[-3,-1,2,-11],[-2,1,2,-3]]
    res = mapr 2 (\x -> map (\y -> y + 1) x) a
  in
    print res
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be easiest to write this in a recursive function

```
mapr n _ [] = error $ "index: "++ show n ++" out of bounds"
mapr n f (x:xx) | n < 0     = error "negative index"
                | n == 0    = f x : xx
                | otherwise = x : mapr (n-1) f xx
```

the following code runs:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do let a = [[2,1,-1,8],[-3,-1,2,-11],[-2,1,2,-3]]
              res = mapr 2 (const []) a
          print res
```

you can replace `const []` with all functions that work on rows - for example `map (+1)` as well.

### Update:

Here is one version that uses `zip` to get indices for comparison, and I have changed the type of the function to work element-wise instead of row wise.

```
mapr' :: Idx -> (El -> El) -> Mat El -> Mat El
mapr' n f xx = map (mapIf n f) $ zip xx [0..]
  where mapIf n f (row,idx) = if idx == n then (map f row)
                                          else row
```

This is a bit terse so, would ask you to fire up ghci and evaluate the following expressions to get a feeling what it does:

- `zip ['a'..'z'] [0..]`
- `map succ ['a'..'c']` and `map (*3) [10,9..1]`
- `let mapIf n f (row,idx) = if idx == n then (map f row) else row`
- `mapIf 1 (*3) ([10,9..1],0)`
- `mapIf 0 (*3) ([10,9..1],0)`
- `map (map (*3)) [[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]`

Comment: Couldn't match type ‘[El]’ with ‘Int’
    Expected type: Row El -> El
      Actual type: Row El -> Row El
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘f’
    In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(map f x)’

Comment: I misread that - I thought you wanted to apply a function to each element of your row.